# Percentage symbol show with number in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am converting a PHP script into excel sheet using PHPExcel library
I want to attach a  % symbol with my number.I am using below script

```
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("E4")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE);  
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit("E4","12",PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

But when I convert the file in PHPExcel result show `1200%` .But I want `12%`. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is multiplied by 100 if you format it as a percentage value...

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php):

> In order to format percentages, create a locale-specific formatter with percentage format type. With this formatter, a decimal fraction such as 0.75 is displayed as 75%.

When formatting percentages, Excel, PHP, and even Java `DecimalFormat` formatting behaves the same.